# Add only distinct elements of an array using a single loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

For example: Given an array:

```
var a = [5,4,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,1];
```

Expected Sum would be: 3+2+6+7 = 18

**There should only be a single for loop in the entire code.**

My Failed Approach:

```
var a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,2]
var expected = 3+4+5+6+8

const sum1 = (a) => {
    var s = 0;
    var ch = {};
    for(let i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(s <0) {
            s = 0;
        }
        if(ch[a[i]]) {
            s -= a[i]
        } else {
            ch[a[i]] = a[i];
            s += a[i];
        }
    }

    return s
}

console.log(sum1(a))
```

Comment: Yes, there can be any number of repetitions

Comment: Shouldn't `expected` be `3+4+5+6+8`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration, add the number being iterated over to the sum. Use a Set to keep track of the numbers which have appeared so far. If the number has been seen *once* before, subtract it from the sum (so that it's as if the number was never added to the sum in the first place). If it's been seen *twice* or more, ignore it, since it's already been subtracted from the sum:

```js
const sumUniques = (input) => {
  let sum = 0;
  // duplicates get put into seenOnce
  // and subtracted from the sum
  const seenOnce = new Set();
  // duplicates in seenTwice get completely ignored;
  // they've already been subtracted from the sum
  const seenTwice = new Set();
  
  input.forEach((num) => {
    if (seenTwice.has(num)) {
      return;
    }
    if (seenOnce.has(num)) {
      sum -= num;
      seenTwice.add(num);
    } else {
      sum += num;
      seenOnce.add(num);
    }
  });
  return sum;
}


console.log(sumUniques([5,4,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,1]))
console.log(sumUniques([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,2]))
```

Comment: Excellent solution, mind if i ask how to get good at competitive programing? Some sources or anything?

Comment: Practice a lot, I suppose, and ask others to review your code when you're unsure if you're following the best pattern, so that when you see a problem with that pattern in the future, you can be sure you're implementing a solution the best way

Comment: been going through hackerrank and others. Bue due to office hours and other tasks, I can't give much time to problem solving. I used to be good with these but have recently lost my touch due to my busy schedule. Solving this problem with two separate loops using hashmaps was easy. I have to train myself to do this in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a map where the key is the element and the value is a count of how many times the element has been encountered.

```
const sum = array => {
    const map = new Map();
    return array.reduce((sum, e) => {
      const seenCount = (map.get(e) || 0) + 1;
      map.set(e, seenCount);
      if (seenCount === 1) {
        sum += e;
      } else if (seenCount === 2) {
        sum -= e;
      }
      return sum;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: @vivek_23 the value is removed from the sum at the 2nd encounter. Nothing happens after the 2nd encounter

Comment: Ahh, overlooked that.

Comment: I believe this is where i went wrong. I wasn't handling the case properly where if the element is seen more than twice we have to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {5,4,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,1,5};
    int sum = 0;

    Set<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> doneList = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if(doneList.contains(arr[i])) continue;

        if (!list.contains(arr[i])) {
            list.add(arr[i]);
            sum += arr[i];
        } else{
            sum -= arr[i];
            doneList.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

}
```